# Saving python print output to variable

Tags: python, python-3.3

i'm trying to print a message on the screen and then also save that in a text file, but if i put it into a variable first, then print it, it displays with things like, and () which i don't want. I'm wondering how I would save the print output to a variable, so that i can then write it to a text file.

```
print("P", count, ": ", "".join(random.choice(chars) for i in range(length)))
```

That is what i have the print as, but if i did this:

```
var = "P", count, ": ", "".join(random.choice(chars) for i in range(length))
```

it would display as this V which I dont want it to.

```
('P ', 314, ': ', 'ZYIAV')
```

Comment: It would also be worth it to check out the `logging` module. It can definitely help for the future. https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [format string syntax](http://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings).

```
result = "P {}: {}".format(count, "".join(random.choice(chars) for i in range(length)))
```

Now `result` contains the string in the format you desire and can be printed as well.